# Hecke operators for modular form with respect to $\Gamma_{\theta}(2)$ subgroup

Tags: modular-forms, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras, hecke-operators

The congruence subgroup $\Gamma_{\theta}(2)$ is defined as:
$$\Gamma_{\theta}(2)=\left\{\gamma\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})|\gamma\equiv\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \operatorname{or} \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)\mod 2\right\}$$
So how to define Hecke operators on modular forms with respect to this group? I also want to ask the same questions for the following two groups:
$$\Gamma_{0}(2)=\left\{\gamma\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})|\gamma\equiv\left(\begin{array}{cc}\ast & \ast\\ 0 & \ast\end{array}\right)\mod 2\right\}$$
and
$$\Gamma^0(2)=\left\{\gamma\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})|\gamma\equiv\left(\begin{array}{cc}\ast & 0\\ \ast & \ast\end{array}\right)\mod 2\right\}$$

In fact, I am wondering whether it is possible to extend the method in arXiv:1804.06860 to the fermionic Rational conformal field theory cases. As it is mentioned in this work, we know that any bosonic rational conformal field theory's characters are modular functions of $\Gamma(N)$ for particular $N$, but I don't know any parallel conclusions for fermionic rational conformal field theory. But I do know that the characters of the theory with particular boundary conditions are vector modular forms of $\Gamma_{\theta}(2)$ or $\Gamma_0(2)$ or $\Gamma^0(2)$, depending on the boundary conditions on the torus.

Comment: There are several papers about modularity properties of characters of representations of Kac-Moody superalgebras which might interest you. For example, [Some characters of Kac and Wakimoto and nonholomorphic modular functions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225731907_Some_characters_of_Kac_and_Wakimoto_and_nonholomorphic_modular_functions) by Bringmann and Ono (2009), or [Almost harmonic Maass forms and
Kac–Wakimoto characters](https://afolsom.people.amherst.edu/BFolsom-preprintCrelle.pdf) by Bringmann and Folsom (2012), and several others